# Drupal и каталог туров за границу

Tags: php, drupal

Всем привет! Появилась задача сделать на друпале систему туров за границу. Без бронирования, просто каталог туров с фильтром по категории, месту назначения, бюджету и тд.
Я с друпалом не знаком, хотел бы спросить у людей у которых есть опыт в друпале.
Стоит ли мне писать целый модуль для этого? Или в друпале есть какой-то универсилизированный инструмент, где я могу настроить поля которые должны быть и запросто сделать каталог туров?

Comment: Я думаю модуль не стоит писать! Списки фильтров создаем через таксономию, далее создаем новый тип материала со всеми необходимыми полями и выводим все через модуль Views. На счет фильтров не могу подсказать, но думаю легко загуглить.

Comment: @Pearson, большое спасибо, посмотрю. Как чувствовал что без модуля можно обойтись)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно ограничиться контрибом:

1. Создать тип материала "Тур"
2. Наполнить полями
3. Создать каталог с фильтрами с помощью модуля Views

Comment: Спасибо, завтра попробую!) Думаю всё сработает норм)